# Linux Operating System and Version, Regardless of Distibution

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I would like to know a linux command that can tell me the operating system and version **regardless** of what distribution I am using as it seems different distributions have a different way of doing this.  That may make such a thing tricky but then again there may be a way and perhaps the community already has this.

Previous questions on this have elicited responses such as "these users have answered that" but then didn't give a link to the answer or indeed previous question, only the users who had ansked the question which makes finding the answer somewhat of a challenge.  Other resposnes to similar questions have been specific to redhat or whatever and as such not an answer to my new question here.

Many thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Have you try using this command: uname -a

Comment: doesnt 'cat /etc/*release' help?

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine with:

```
cat /proc/version
```

Comment: This only provides the kernel version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lsb_release -a` which is already installed or available in most Linux distributions.